# A shell script to mount a disk image file

Tags: bash, linux, shell

I'm trying to create a bash shell script which mounts a disk image file. Not only that but checks to see if the disk image already exists. Is there anyway I could improve my script? Currently my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

MOUNTPOINT="/myfilesystem"

if [ ! -d "${MOUNTPOINT}" ]; then
    if [ -e "${MOUNTPOINT}" ]; then
        echo "Mountpoint exists, but isn't a directory..."
        exit 1
    else
        sudo mkdir -p "${MOUNTPOINT}"
    fi
fi

if [ "$(echo ${MOUNTPOINT}/*)" != "${MOUNTPOINT}/*" ]; then
    echo "Mountpoint is not empty!"
    exit 1
fi

if mountpoint -q "${MOUNTPOINT}"; then
    echo "Already mounted..."
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The first conditional group can be reorganized to make it flatter and simpler:

```
if [ ! -e "${MOUNTPOINT}" ]; then
    sudo mkdir -p "${MOUNTPOINT}"
elif [ -d "${MOUNTPOINT}" ]; then
    echo "Mountpoint exists, but isn't a directory..."
    exit 1
fi
```

The `exit 0` is pointless in the last condition,
and as such, you could replace it with a one-liner using `&&`:

```
mountpoint -q "${MOUNTPOINT}" && echo "Already mounted..."
```

Answer (score 1):

- Error messages should be printed on standard error, like `echo "Chocolate missing!" >&2
- Internal variables should be lowercase, like `mount_point`. Don't worry if it ends up being the same string as a command like `mountpoint`; Bash handles that just fine (and your IDE should highlight them to show the difference).
- The [idiomatic Bash shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) is `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (disclaimer: my answer)
- `sudo` is generally discouraged within scripts, for at least two reasons:

  1. The target system may not have `sudo`. This is uncommon, but some use `su` instead.
  2. It makes it harder to automate the use of the script, since `sudo` may prompt for a password.
- It is generally expected of a shell script that it will not have unintended side effects. Your script will create the mount point directory if it doesn't exist.
- Instead of hard coding your mount point you can easily make the script … scriptable:

  ```
  for mount_point
  do
      [the contents of your script]
  done
  ```

  this will loop through all the arguments you provide (`"$@"`)
- I personally prefer moving the `then` and `do` keywords to a separate line, to avoid having to use `;` in my scripts.